# How do i delete buttons after theyre created and clicked

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, button

I'm trying to delete buttons from a table after they're created and clicked. I used two functions, one for the creation and one for the deletion, and so far only one button is deleted, the rest don't delete even after I created and clicked them
I used the function 'ajouter' to create the button and append it to the table, then I used the 'test 'function to delete the button, so far, only one button is deleted. I couldn't figure it out

```js
function ajouter() {
    let titre = document.getElementById('titre').value;
    let auteur = document.getElementById('auteur').value;
    let année = document.getElementById('année').value;
    let table = document.getElementById('myTable');


    let newRow = table.insertRow(1);
    let Cell1 = newRow.insertCell(0);
    let Cell2 = newRow.insertCell(1);
    let Cell3 = newRow.insertCell(2);


    Cell1.innerHTML = titre;
    Cell2.innerHTML = auteur;
    Cell3.innerHTML = année;


    var button = document.createElement("button");
    button.innerHTML = "Delete";
    button.setAttribute('id', 'buttons');
    Cell3.appendChild(button);
    return (false);
};



if (ajouter() == false) {
    buttons = document.getElementsByTagName('button');
    console.log(buttons + "test")
    for (i = 0; i < buttons.length; i++) {

        a = buttons[i].parentElement
        buttons[i].addEventListener('click', function () {
            console.log("test");
            a.parentElement.remove();
        });

    };
};
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>Book store</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css">
</head>
<body>
    
<div class="container">
    <h1 class="title">Ajouter un livre</h1>

    <label for="titre">Titre:</label>
    <input type="text" name="titre" id="titre">

    <label for="Auteur">Auteur:</label>
    <input type="text" name="Auteur" id="auteur">

    <label for="Année">Année:</label>
    <input type="text" name="Année" id="année">

    <input type="submit" value="Ajouter" onclick="ajouter()">
</div>

<div class="table-container">
    <table id="myTable">
        <tr>
          
          <th>Titre</th>
          <th>Auteur </th>
          <th>Année</th>
        </tr>
        
      
      </table>
</div>

<script src="javascript.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

In your script you attach the click event handler *only* once to the already existing "delete" button(s):

```
if (ajouter() == false) {
    buttons = document.getElementsByTagName('button');
    ...
    for (i = 0; i < buttons.length; i++) {
        ...
        buttons[i].addEventListener('click', function () { ... })
        });
    };
};
```

All "delete"-buttons that are created later by your "ajouter" function will not have a click-event-handler attached to them.

Maybe the following is more what you want? In my snippet I applied the DRY (do not repeat yourself) rule vigorously:

- First I declare a constant `D` as an object.
- The object's properties are then defined as certain DOM elements, identified through their `id` attributes.
- The "ajouter" click-event-handler-function is then directly assigned to the onclick event of the ajouter button
- Inside the function a new DOM element `tr` is created, filled with content from the three input fields and `append()`ed to the `<tbody id="tbd">` element (`D.tbd`).
- The "delete" buttons are created as simple `<button>`s.

Outside the "ajouter" function a delegated click event is assigned to `D.tbd`. This will only result in action, if the clicked element's Tag name (`ev.target.tagName`) was `"BUTTON"`. Then it's `.closest("tr")` parent element is searched and `.remove()`d.

```js
const D={}; // global constant
["auteur","titre","annee","ajouter","tbd"].forEach(e=>
 D[e]=document.getElementById(e));

D.ajouter.onclick=()=>{
 const tr = document.createElement("tr");
 tr.innerHTML=`<td>${D.titre.value}</td>
  <td>${D.auteur.value}</td><td>${D.annee.value}</td>
  <td><button>delete</button></td>`;
 D.tbd.append(tr);
}

D.tbd.onclick=ev=>{
 if(ev.target.tagName==="BUTTON")
  ev.target.closest("tr").remove();
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
 <h1 class="title">Ajouter un livre</h1>
 <label for="titre">Titre:</label>
 <input type="text" name="titre" id="titre"><be>
 <label for="Auteur">Auteur:</label>
 <input type="text" name="Auteur" id="auteur"></br>
 <label for="Année">Année:</label>
 <input type="text" name="Année" id="annee">&nbsp;<button id="ajouter">Ajouter</button>
</div>

<div class="table-container">
 <table><thead>
  <tr><th>Titre</th><th>Auteur </th><th>Année</th></tr>
  </thead><tbody id="tbd"><tbody>
 </table>
</div>
```

Comment: Thank you for helping me and sorry for any confusion regarding the french language,it is a project for school